# VBA PasteSpecial random "quotes"

Tags: excel, vba

I experiencing what seems to be a random issue with using VBA PasteSpecial to copy data from one Excel workbook to another text file. I'm getting some data elements with quotes before and after.

Using this in VBA

```vb
Windows(fsname).Activate
ActiveSheet.Calculate
Range(d).Copy

Windows(bsname).Activate
Range("a1").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Selection.Replace What:="""", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
        
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=loutfile, FileFormat:=xlTextWindows
```

Example snip

```
"OP|99999999999|1|2023-05-10 00:00:00|10111673-2-AC-M-0-0-11-7100297|CATARACT KIT, PREOP|10111673|7100297|AMBULATORY CARE UNIT||MEDICARE||||||MB0||||CAH471305"
OP|08065183150|1|2023-05-10 00:00:00|10111673-2-AC-M-0---7100475|DUOVISC 0.55ML SYRINGE|10111673|7100475|AMBULATORY CARE UNIT||MEDICARE||||||MB0||||CAH471305
OP|00143959525|1|2023-05-10 00:00:00|10111673-2-AC-M-0-0-10-7100803|LIDOCAINE MPF INJ SDV 1% 5ML|10111673|7100803|AMBULATORY CARE UNIT||MEDICARE||||||MB0||||CAH471305
OP|23155060041|1|2023-05-10 00:00:00|10111673-2-AC-M-0-0-13-7100894|MIDAZOLAM INJ SDV: 2MG/2ML|10111673|7100894|AMBULATORY CARE UNIT||MEDICARE||||||MB0||||CAH471305
OP|24208073006|1|2023-05-10 00:00:00|10111673-2-AC-M-0-0-12-7101133|PROPARACAINE HCL OPTH SOLN 0.5% 15ML|10111673|7101133|AMBULATORY CARE UNIT||MEDICARE||||||MB0||||CAH471305
OP|62225060004|1|2023-05-10 00:00:00|10111673-2-AC-M-0-0-9-7101545|PHENYLEPH/KETOR OPTH SDV 1%/0.3% 4ML|10111673|7101545|AMBULATORY CARE UNIT||MEDICARE||||||MB0||||CAH471305
OP|00065179504|1|2023-05-10 00:00:00|10111673-2-AC-M-0---7101556|BALANCED SALT SOLUTION OPTH 500ML BAG|10111673|7101556|AMBULATORY CARE UNIT||MEDICARE||||||MB0||||CAH471305
"OP|99999999999|1|2023-05-10 00:00:00|10112610-2-AC-M-0-1-3-7100297|CATARACT KIT, PREOP|10112610|7100297|AMBULATORY CARE UNIT||MEDICARE||||||MB0||||CAH471305"
OP|08065183150|1|2023-05-10 00:00:00|10112610-2-AC-M-0-1-6-7100475|DUOVISC 0.55ML SYRINGE|10112610|7100475|AMBULATORY CARE UNIT||MEDICARE||||||MB0||||CAH471305
OP|00143959525|1|2023-05-10 00:00:00|10112610-2-AC-M-0-1-2-7100803|LIDOCAINE MPF INJ SDV 1% 5ML|10112610|7100803|AMBULATORY CARE UNIT||MEDICARE||||||MB0||||CAH471305
OP|23155060041|1|2023-05-10 00:00:00|10112610-2-AC-M-0-1-5-7100894|MIDAZOLAM INJ SDV: 2MG/2ML|10112610|7100894|AMBULATORY CARE UNIT||MEDICARE||||||MB0||||CAH471305
OP|24208073006|1|2023-05-10 00:00:00|10112610-2-AC-M-0-1-4-7101133|PROPARACAINE HCL OPTH SOLN 0.5% 15ML|10112610|7101133|AMBULATORY CARE UNIT||MEDICARE||||||MB0||||CAH471305
OP|08065183905|1|2023-05-10 00:00:00|10112610-2-AC-M-0-1-7-7101484|VISCOAT OPTH INJ SYR: 20MG/15MG/0.5ML|10112610|7101484|AMBULATORY CARE UNIT||MEDICARE||||||MB0||||CAH471305
OP|62225060004|1|2023-05-10 00:00:00|10112610-2-AC-M-0-1-1-7101545|PHENYLEPH/KETOR OPTH SDV 1%/0.3% 4ML|10112610|7101545|AMBULATORY CARE UNIT||MEDICARE||||||MB0||||CAH471305
OP|00065179504|1|2023-05-10 00:00:00|10112610-2-AC-M-0---7101556|BALANCED SALT SOLUTION OPTH 500ML BAG|10112610|7101556|AMBULATORY CARE UNIT||MEDICARE||||||MB0||||CAH471305
"OP|99999999999|1|2023-05-10 00:00:00|10113281-2-AC-M-0-0-16-7100297|CATARACT KIT, PREOP|10113281|7100297|AMBULATORY CARE UNIT||MEDICARE||||||MB3||||CAH471305"
```

I tried adding in this to find and replace the quotes

```vb
Selection.Replace What:="""", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: Please add sufficient code to show exactly what you are copying.

Comment: Apparently you are copying from CSV. Apparently the entire line in that CSV is considered a single field because `|` has not been set up as a separator. Apparently when that single field contains a comma, double quotes are added around it as it is customary in CSV.